# Django - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource when making a POST

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, nginx, python-requests

Whenever I make a request.post inside my custom authentication class, the response takes a while and then throws me this error (502)

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://54.185.235.97:8000/rest-auth/login/' from origin
>   'http://ec2-54-185-235-97.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' has been
>   blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource.

Here is the code (This code send an email to the user to reset the password if he/she exceed the numbers of login attempts)

```
headers = {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
requests.post(                                   
    "http://ec2-54-185-235-97.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/rest-auth/password/reset/",
                                            data={'email': user.email},
                                            headers=headers
                                        )

                                        user.is_blocked = True
                                        user.save()
                                        attemptsObject.delete()
                                        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(('User Blocked'))
```

This code works fine in my development workspace, but somehow gets trouble inside my AWS instance, is it something to do with my Nginx configuration? or do I need to create a Custom CORS middleware class?

Nginx:

```
upstream django_app {
  server unix:/var/www/backend/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=10s;
}

server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;
    access_log /var/www/backend/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /var/www/backend/logs/nginx-error.log warn;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;


        proxy_pass http://django_app;

         }
        location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }
}
```

Comment: Where you've got that error?

Comment: Chrome inspector console

Comment: So I believe the error come from UI code, not from the code that you included on your question. Seem like on the login page, your code is trying to send a request to this endpoint: `http://ec2-54-185-235-97.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`. So it could be easier if you can provide your template on login page.

Comment: You can take a look on this answer for some information about CORS and how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899439/aws-api-gateway-with-angular/54494252#54494252