# django & javascript fetch(): CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, cors

I am trying to make an ajax call. I am using `django 2.2.5` and `cors 3.1.0`, but getting the following error messages in the browser console:

> (index):1 Access to fetch at 'http://sub.example.com/' from origin
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>
> (index):798 GET http://sub.example.com/ net::ERR_FAILED
>
> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
>   http://sub.example.com/ with MIME type text/plain. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

My ajax call looks like this:

```
    setInterval(function() {
        fetch('http://my.domain.com/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => myHtmlTag.innerText = json.data)
    }, 5000 );
```

I have installed `django-cors-headers` and my django `settings.py` look like this, but it doesn't work anyway:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://my.domain.com/',
]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://my.domain.com/',
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

The raw response data, which I get from the server if I test it with e.g. Insomnia is:

```
{"data":"0123456789"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add the requester in the allowed origins. In your case you should add http://localhost:8000

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look to see how CORS work on your browser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899439/aws-api-gateway-with-angular/54494252#answer-54494252).

In your case, you could change `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` to this:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    'http://any.host.want.to.allow.to.access.this.server.com',
]
```

Comment: try this one to see if that working or not: `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True`

Comment: Set `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True`, cleared cache, still the same error.

Comment: Could you also provide the logs? Because if the API response with error status codes then you still got `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error

Comment: What kind of logs do you need? I have updated the error message, this is what I get from the browser

Comment: Seem like it's not a CORS problem but the response data of `http://sub.example.com/`. Are you sure that `http://sub.example.com/` working properly?

Comment: Yes, if I test it with Insomnia, I get a response object, but with django I get an error message: `...blocked by CORS policy`

Comment: try to make the response in `json` format then, due to this message `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://sub.example.com/ with MIME type text/plain`

Comment: But doesn't this just mean, that a  response with MIME type text was blocked. I could also have needed a text response, which I would handle with `response.text()`

Comment: Can you deploy your app on your localhost too? So that you can trace to see if the request reached or not. Or if reached, what is the issue